# Is the lazy version of the 'optional' quantifier ('??') ever useful in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I cannot think of a situation where I'd want to use `??` in a regular expression, but maybe I'm not thinking hard enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe a delimiter-separated list, and you don't want to match any terminating delimiter.

```
^((?:[^,]+,??)+),?$
```

That would capture `"a,b,c"` from `"a,b,c,"`, where as the non-lazy variant would include the comma in the capture-group.

Comment: Maybe it's just the flavor I'm using, but that seems to match just the a and the b and the c; no delimiters. Which makes sense, because '??' will always be able to match nothing, and since it's lazy, it will always choose nothing, no?

Comment: Wait you changed it, so what I said probably no longer applies. I still see it matching the last comma though.

Comment: It matches the last comma, but does not capture it in the group.

Comment: You don't need ?? to achieve this:

^((?:[^,]+,)*[^,]+),?$

Comment: There are several ways to do most things.

Answer (score 2):

I would use it as an optimization if the optional part is usually absent.

```
Foo(PartUsuallyPresent)?Bar

Foo(PartUsuallyAbsent)??Bar
```

But I definitly lack a real-world example, too.