# regex: question mark followed by colon as an alternative

Tags: ruby, regex, cucumber

In rails cucumber there is this regex 
 `When /^(?:|I )go to (.+)$/ do |page_name|`

I know `?:` is a non-capturing group but what does it mean when it is there as an alternative separated by `|` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a special group, it just means "match nothing or `I`": http://www.rubular.com/r/H3iJFLXaab

This should be the same as writing `(?:I )?`
<sup>(or to be more precise, `(?:I )??` - because the empty string has precedence over `I`, see also [Is the lazy version of the 'optional' quantifier ('??') ever useful in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/978932/7586) )</sup>

Comment: I've found some Cucumber examples, and all are using `(?:|I )go` - I'm investigating why...

Comment: According to [Cucumber Regular Expressions Cheat Sheet](http://35qk152ejao6mi5pan29erbr9.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Cucumber-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet.pdf), both are supported.